# Django template if condition on a key

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a for loop through a dictionary. And I would like to have a condition on my key but I get an error.

Here is my code :

```
{% for key, value in price_list.items %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span style="margin-top: 7px;">
            {{key}}
        </span>
        <span style="color: #F60;font-weight: bold;">
            {{value}}€
        </span>
        {% if {{key}} == 'Krefel' %}
            <a class="flux_cta gift__cta" href="#" style="font-size: 13px;height: 41px;float: right;padding-top: 11px;margin-right: 10%;" >
     Voir l'offre
            </a>
        {% endif %}
```

I can't just check if the key is part of the dictonary as I am in a for loop. Any idea how I can adress the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not wrap variables in extra curly brackets, the condition is:

```
{% if key == 'Krefel' %}
    …
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed what I need to do!

Answer (score 0):

Pull the brackets out of your `if` statement:

```
{% if key == 'Krefel' %}
   <a class="flux_cta gift__cta" href="#" style="font-size: 13px;height: 41px;float: right;padding-top: 11px;margin-right: 10%;" >
Voir l'offre
</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed what I need to do!